# Let $\xi$ be the fifth primitive root of $1$ an let $\zeta= \xi + \frac{1}{\xi}$. Prove that $\zeta^2 + \zeta =1$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\xi$ be the fifth primitive root of $1$ an let $\zeta= \xi + \frac{1}{\xi}$. Prove that $\zeta^2 + \zeta =1$

In my attempt I used $\xi = \cos(72k) + i\sin(72k)$ with $k=1,2,3,4$

Where I got $\zeta = \frac{1+\cos(144k)+i\sin(144k)}{\cos(72k)+i\sin(72k)}$

Which yielded $\zeta^2 + \zeta = 2\cos(72k)(2\cos(72k)+1)$

I don’t know what else I could do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, $\xi^5 = 1$ and we have the factorization $$\prod_{k=0}^4 (z - \xi^k) = z^5 - 1.$$  But since $(z - \xi^0) = (z - 1)$, it follows that $$\prod_{k=1}^4 (z - \xi^k) = \frac{z^5 - 1}{z-1} = 1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4,$$ hence $$1 + \xi + \xi^2 + \xi^3 + \xi^4 = 0.$$  Dividing by $\xi^2$ yields $$\begin{align*}0 
&= \xi^{-2} + \xi^{-1} + 1 + \xi + \xi^2 \\
&= (\xi^2 + 2 + \xi^{-2}) + (\xi + \xi^{-1}) - 1 \\
&= (\xi + \xi^{-1})^2 + (\xi + \xi^{-1}) - 1 \\
&= \zeta^2 + \zeta - 1. \end{align*}$$

Comment: Great! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Write $\zeta= \xi + \dfrac{1}{\xi} = \xi + \xi^4$, because $\xi^5=1$. Then 
$$\zeta^2 + \zeta = \xi^2 + 2\xi \xi^4 + \xi^8 + \xi + \xi^4 = \xi^2 + 2 + \xi^3 + \xi + \xi^4 = 1 + 1 + \xi + \xi^2 + \xi^3 + \xi^4 = 1
$$
because $1 + \xi + \xi^2 + \xi^3 + \xi^4 = 0$, since $0=\xi^5-1=(\xi-1)(1 + \xi + \xi^2 + \xi^3 + \xi^4)$ and $\xi \ne 1$.