# Olympiad Math Question - If α is a root of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 = 0$, find the value of $α + \frac{1}{α}$

Tags: contest-math, roots

I'm going through some Olympiad math pass papers, and came across this question:

> If α is a root of $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1 = 0$, find the value of $α + \frac{1}{α}$

I think there's two things that are weird about this question.

1. Did they actually mean this:

> The root of $y = x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$

2. I tried to graph this in Desmos, but it seems that all the roots are imaginary. However, this is a multiple choice question, and none of the answers were imaginary.

[[image: <span class=]$y = x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZK4Cy.png)

In case you're curious, here were the multiple choices:

$$A) \frac{1\pm\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$B) \frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$
$$C) \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$D) \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

By the way, why is this even an Olympiad question? I thought Olympiad maths were supposed to be about shortcuts, and it seems like that a shortcut wouldn't help to solve this question.

Comment: 1) Just because $\alpha $ is not real (not necessarily imaginary), that doesn't mean that that an expression of $\alpha$ can't be real. EG For $i$ is not real, but $i + \frac{1}{i}$ is real. 2) Olympiad problems are not about shortcuts, but about understanding the material.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is such a number, then $\alpha^5 -1 = 0$ and $\alpha \ne 1$. Therefore $\alpha = e^{2 k \pi i/5}$ with $k \in \{1, 2,3,4\}$ and $\alpha^{-1} = \bar \alpha$. Take it from there.

Comment: Note that $\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$. Now see what happens if we divide both sides by $\alpha^2$ (and remember the identity $t^2+\frac{1}{{t}^{2}}=\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)^2 -2$).

Comment: On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3h1609981p10050515

Comment: (Almost?) duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3386226/42969

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: $\alpha\ne0$, and $\alpha^4+\alpha^3+\alpha^2+\alpha+1=0$. Then?

> Then $\alpha^2+\alpha+1+\frac1\alpha+\frac1{\alpha^2}=0$. Substituting $\alpha+\frac1\alpha=t$, then $t^2+t-1=0$.
> Solution is $t=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt5}2$.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach/hint: Let $ z = \alpha + \frac{1}{\alpha}$.
Find a quadratic in $z$.
Hence, apply the quadratic formula to find $z$.